# Embedded PDF contents when performing a File->print

Tags: html, internet-explorer, pdf, web, printing

I have a PDF file embedded into a standard html web page.

```html
<h3>Foo</h3>
<object  id="foo" data="bigboundingbox.pdf" 
    type="application/pdf" 
      classid="clsid:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000"> </object>
```

This currently renders in Internet Explorer using the Adobe Reader plugin on windows. Firefox and Chrome appear to be using their internal PDF rendering engines.

In all 3 cases the page displays with the Foo header visible above the contents of the PDF.

When a user tries to print the page (File->print), the PDF being rendered does not display in the resulting printed document in Internet Explorer or Chrome.

Firefox appears to display correctly.

- I have tried using PDFObject in order to embed this with the same result
- There are other posts recommending using PDF.js etc.. however I *must* support IE 7 *and* IE 8 and PDF.js will not work at all with 7 and works with limited success with 8.

Does anyone know why this happens and if there is anything i can modify so that it will print ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use fpdf for that. Have a look at fpdf [here](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fpdf.org%2F&ei=VzY8VYf-EMGqoQTU1IGIDQ&usg=AFQjCNHE8XIPz0SsbbOy13jIM_vhJTbrdQ&sig2=2KlRjfKqNojEA-7Ykjvv-w&bvm=bv.91665533,d.cGU)